# Can't get fadeIn() to work on addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been stuck with this for a while now and I still can't get it to work. I have this bit of JavaScript that uses `addClass` and `removeClass` to show and hides a submenu element. The `addclass` and `removeClass` both work and I've been trying to get the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to work as well. I've tried the `animate` function but none have helped so far. Someone also told me to use `toggleClass` instead, I will look into that a bit later

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    function t(t) {
        e(t).bind("click", function (t) {
            t.preventDefault();
            e(this).parent();
        });
    }
    e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden");
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
        e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
        if (t) {
            e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active"); //i believe that this is where i need to toggle the fadeIn and FadeOut
        }
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")){ 
            e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").hide();
        }
    });
    e(document).bind("click", function (t) {
        var n = e(t.target);
        if (!n.parents().hasClass("button-dropdown")){
            e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active"); 
        }
    })
});
```

The HTML for this:

```html
<nav class="nav2">
 <a href="profile.php" class="imglink"><img src="img/icon-profile.png" WIDTH=40 HEIGHT=40></a>
 <li class="button-dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="img/cart.png" class="cart"WIDTH=40 HEIGHT=40></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="list-style:none;">
   <p>
    <h2 class="profileH2">Winkelwagen</h2>
   </p>
  </ul>
 </li>
</nav>
```

Basically this shows and hides the submenu of `button-dropdown`. Who can help me with this?

Thanks

The JavaScript code I found was on codepen from a random google search. If you happen to be the writer of this, let me know and I'll credit you for it. Thank you.

Comment: First, I have to say it's really strange that your passing in jQuery as 'e' instead of '$'.  Other than that, I found it strange that you have two almost identical bindings for 'e(document).bind("click", function (t)'

Comment: @Taplar: it is uncommon, but it's prefectly valid. `$` or `e` or `whateverYouLike` is just a substitute for `jQuery`. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: I wasn't saying it was not valid.

Comment: Waro, you might want to provide a [mcve]. As you might have noticed, your snippet is not working. You need to replace the relative links with absolute ones and also load the required assets (if any). Make it work and we'll answer.

Comment: You may also need to supply the css, specifically the styling for the `active` class.  My [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34582507/1059070) adds and removes this class as desired, but I can't verify any style changes that might accompany this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) for [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) for [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) (which is always the equivalent of [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) since you always [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it first).

https://jsfiddle.net/eyemsa34/

```
e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    var t = e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").is(":hidden");
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").fadeOut();
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").removeClass("active");
    if (t) {
        e(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-menu").fadeIn().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active"); //i believe that this is where i need to toggle the fadeIn and FadeOut
    }
});
```

You can also use [`fadeToggle`](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) and [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to have jQuery handle the toggling logic for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/eyemsa34/1/

```
e(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-menu").fadeToggle();
    e(".button-dropdown .dropdown-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Glad to help. FYI, you can only accept one answer, but you can also upvote to "mark as useful".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer, or complete answer.  It's not using addClass, but it does do some fading.  Maybe it will lead to the answer.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 var $dropdownMenus = $('.dropdown-menu');
    
    $dropdownMenus.hide();
    
    $(".dropdown-toggle").on('click', function() {
     var $toggle = $(this),
         $toggleContainer = $toggle.parent(),
            $toggleMenu = $toggleContainer.find('.dropdown-menu');
        
        if ($toggleMenu.is(':hidden')) {
         $dropdownMenus.fadeOut('slow');
           $toggleMenu.fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
         $toggleMenu.fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav2">
 <li class="button-dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <img src="img/cart.png" class="cart"WIDTH=40 HEIGHT=40>
        </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="list-style:none;">
   <li>
    <h2 class="profileH2">Winkelwagen</h2>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="button-dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <img src="img/cart.png" class="cart"WIDTH=40 HEIGHT=40>
        </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="list-style:none;">
   <li>
    <h2 class="profileH2">Winkelwagen</h2>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</nav>
```